# Binding List<MyObject> to a repeater

Tags: data-binding, c#-4.0, repeater, datarepeater

I have a complicated class which is something like:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int Pid;
        IList<Address> Addressess;
        public Name Name;
        public Name PartnerName;

        Person(int id)
        {
            Addressess = new List<Address>();
        }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string HouseName;
        public string street;
        public string country;
        public string universe;
        public string galaxy;
    }

    public class Name
    {
        public string Firstname;
        public string Lastname;
        public string Fullname { get { return Firstname + " " + Lastname; } }
    }
```

So, now, when I bind the repeater like so:

```
rpPeople.DataSource = PeopleNearYou; //this is a List<Person>();
```

and in the actual repeater, I want to show the details. To access, say, `Pid`, all I need to do is:

```
<%# Eval("Pid") %>
```

Now, I can't figure out how to access the full name in repeater

```
<%# Eval("Fullname") %> //error, fullname not found
```

Also, I want to display only First Address **only** and I can't do that

```
<%# Eval("Address").First().Universe %> //red, glarring error. can't figure out how
```

So, how would I display these stuff please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be so much easier if you grab required class members when you bind the repeater.

```
rpPeople.DataSource = PeopleNearYou.Select(r => new
      {
           Pid = r.Pid,
           Universe = r.Addressess.First().Universe,
           Fullname = r.Name.Fullname
      }
```

Now all you need to do in your repeater is:

```
<%# Eval("Universe") %>
<%# Eval("Fullname") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get in to complicated situations like this I always use the ItemDataBound event as you can get much more control.  For example, in your situation I would create a label in the item template, bind the ItemDataBound to code similar to this...

```
void rpt1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblFullName")).Text = ((Person)e.Item.DataItem).FullName;
}
```

You'll need a check on e.Item.Type too if you have header/footer rows.

Comment: but it is a lot of overhead just to get the data don't you think?